# File Download via shdocvw.dll with custom headers

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to download a really large file in msaccess via a vba application.

Using the objects MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 result in an error stating that there is not enough storage available to complete this operation. Therefore i resorted in using  the DoFileDownload method from shdocvw.dll.
What i want to do is pass an extra header (an API key) to the request sent by the function.

Here is roughly what i want to do.

```
Private Declare Function DoFileDownload Lib "shdocvw.dll" _
  (ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long


Public Sub Download()
    sDownloadFile = StrConv(<link_to_download>, vbUnicode)
    'set a header before calling DoFileDownload
    Call DoFileDownload(sDownloadFile)
End Sub
```

How do i approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Office is x86? Then you re limitrf to max 2GB ram for an x86 process. File is that large?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thanks for trying to help and welcoming me to SO! I thought about the RAM size issue after seeing others having similar issues, but the thing is that the file is a couple hundred MB at most (~250MB). Office version is x86 (32bit)

Comment: Can you show some sample code/link?

Comment: Sure, check this link. https://pastebin.com/4NLabnfB Using this code, downloading a file larger than ~250MB results in an error. That's why i'm trying to use DoFileDownload.

Answer (score 0):

A WebRequest downloading a whole file at once stores the whole data in response.

Although there are options to chunk response, using [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is less coding, but more options.

```vb
Private Sub DownloadFileWget()
Const PathToWget As String = "" 'if wget is not in path use  "Path\To\Wget"
Dim LinkToFile As String
Dim SavePath As String

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    LinkToFile = "http://download.windowsupdate.com/microsoftupdate/v6/wsusscan/wsusscn2.cab" 'huge file > 500MB
    SavePath = "C:\doc" 'folder to save download
    .CurrentDirectory = SavePath
    .Run Chr(34) & PathToWget & "wget.exe" & Chr(34) & " --header='name: value' " & Chr(34) & LinkToFile & Chr(34) & " -N", 1, True
     ' -N: Continue download only if the local version is outdated.
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using the WScript.Shell method, but instead of wget which is not available on my systems, i'm using bitsadmin and i get a type mismatch error. Here is a pastebin to my code. Any ideas?

https://pastebin.com/A972ebaF

Comment: Your double-quotes don't fit. `""`gets`"`inside string, to end string you need a third d-quote. Easier to use`Chr(34)`for double-quotes inside strings. Put you shell code into a seperate string and you can debug.print it.

Comment: It was a permission error. Tested on a privileged host and it worked. Thing is, my deployment host won't have elevated rights or wget.exe. I still think our only solution is the Internet Explorer API.